# Test if element already has jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a form with many input elements. Some are date fields with a jQuery UI datepicker alraedy attached:

```
$("#someElement").mask("9?9/99/9999").datepicker({showOn: 'button', buttonText:'Click here to show calendar', duration: 'fast', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: /images/calicon.gif' });
```

Then I have a key command bound to this function:

```
function openCalendar() {
    var selection = document.activeElement;

    // { Need to test here if datepicker has already been initialized 
        $(selection).datepicker("show");
    // }
}
```

This works great for elements which already have the datepicker on them. However any other fields will throw a javascript error. I'm wondering the best way to test to see if datepicker has already been initialized on that field.

Comment: if(jQuery(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker'))

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Wow can't believe I missed this one. Line 108 of ui.datepicker.js:

```
/* Class name added to elements to indicate already configured with a date picker. */
markerClassName: 'hasDatepicker',
```

So I just need to test for `hasClass('hasDatepicker')`. This seems like the most straightforward way. Furthermore, this statement checks whether the datepicker is currently opened (for anyone who is interested):

```
if ($("#ui-datepicker-div").is(":visible") && $("#ui-datepicker-div").html() != "") {
    // datepicker is open. you need the second condition because it starts off as visible but empty
}
```

Comment: To check if jQuery UI autocomplete is initialized, i have used this: `$('#myinput').is(':data(autocomplete)')`. I assume this also works for datepicker.

Comment: Just because the marker class exists doesn't always mean that the datepicker is on the node.  In Datatables when it shifts to card view the datepicker is removed from the node, but the class stays!  So you need to add the extra check as above AND remove the class if you need to rebind since datepicker internally uses the class as a proxy to prevent multiple binds.

Answer (score 14):

1) If the code throws an error when trying to open the datepicker, you can put the code into try..catch

2) You can set some data to the input field when initializing the datepicker

```
$("#someElement").data("datepicker-initialized", true);
```

3) You can use the data stored by datepicker plugin

```
if($("#someElement").data("datepicker") != null){
   // datepicker initialized
}
```

or

```
if($.data($('#someElement').get(0), 'datepicker')){
   // datepicker initialized
}
```

4) datepicker internally uses a function _getInst

```
if($.datepicker._getInst($('#someElement')[0]) != null){}
```

the method does almost the same as example 3.

Couldn't find any better solution.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me alot.

Comment: `if($("#someElement").data("datepicker") !== null)` isn't exactly right, due to `data()` returning `undefined`, not `null`. A less strict `!=` comparison works though.

Comment: I checked jQuery 1.5, which was the latest release in April 2010, to be sure that it returns `undefined` or `null`. It returned `undefined`. I updated my answer. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

One basic solution is to set an attribute at time of the datepicker attachment and then test for that:

```
$("#someElement").mask("9?9/99/9999")
.datepicker({showOn: 'button', buttonText:'Click here to show calendar', duration: 'fast', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: /images/calicon.gif' })
.attr("data-calendar", "true");
```

Then you could do:

```
if ($(selection).attr("data-calendar") == "true")
    $(selection).datepicker("show");
```

Is there a more direct way?

Comment: I like this approach but I would use `addClass("data-calendar")`, which would then allow you to use a simple selector like this: `$(".data-calendar").datepicker("show");`.

Answer (score 0):

I got another case. 
My script is copying last table elements including datepicker.

The jquery will not working because the copied element has mark that it "hasDatepicker".

To activate datepicker in new element, remove that class name and the initiate it, like this.

```
 $("#yournewelementid").attr("class","your-class-name"); 
 $("#yournewelementid").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

If section is your dom element for datepicker, check if already initialized and if not initialize it first as datepicker (you could add properties) and then show it!

```
    // If already initialized        
    if ( typeof selection !== 'undefined' && selection.length > 0)
         $(selection).datepicker('show');
    // otherwise initialize first and show
    else 
         $(selection).datepicker().datepicker('show');
```

Comment: Please don't just provide a blob of code in an Answer. Give some context and explanation of why you think this solves the problem. The idea is to create a body of Q&A that helps this specific persons _and_ others in the future with generally useful information.

Answer (score -2):

This was my solution :)

```
if(typeof jQuery.fn.datepicker !== "undefined")
```

Comment: This is test if in current window is datepicker available, not if it's on input.