# Test if element already has Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

I am working on a rather big software platform that has several implementations. There is one previous implementation that uses jQueryUI datepicker, and I am now working on an interface revamp that uses Bootstrap datepicker.

Is there a way for me to test whether a Bootstrap datepicker is already attached to a certain element, let's say this one

```
<input type="text" id="user-date" class="datepicker"/>
```

Notice that I am not asking whether Bootstrap datepicker is loaded as in [this qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532287/check-if-bootstrap-datepicker-script-has-loaded). I'm rather asking for a test, similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579389/test-if-element-already-has-jquery-datepicker) for jQueryUI datepicker.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

when you use bootstrap-datepicker on a element it adds a object in .data("datepicker") so you can just check if it exists and to check if the datepicker is visible you can use the .data("datepicker").picker object like this

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="user-date" class="datepicker"/>
```

JS

```
if(!$('#user-date').data('datepicker')){// or $('#user-date').data('datepicker')==null
    console.log('datepicker is not attached');
}   
$('#user-date').datepicker();
$('#user-date').focus();//set focus to display datepicker
if($('#user-date').data('datepicker')){
    console.log('datepicker is already attached');
    if($('#user-date').data('datepicker').picker.is(":visible")){
        console.log("datepicker is visible");
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/weso8a96/

Comment: `.data('datepicker')` is always full whether the input was initialized with datepicker or not, so the test is always true